# Java object parameters and recursion

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence

I have a board game and currently implementing the AI using Negamax to search for positions.When starting a new search, I pass the board object to the class and make a copy of it. The copy is a private variable in the class. I do this because java doesn't pass objects by reference (as I've learned recently).

In the search class, I have 2 functions:

1. NegamaxRoot
   This is the root. I get the initial moves, make the move, call the recursive negamax function (2) and then undo the move.
2. NegamaxRecur
   This function is the main recursive function. Here I get the moves (of the same board copy), make the move, call itself recursively and then undo the move.

This process is basically not working, because when stepping through the debugger, I noticed that object variables are out of sync when doing move/undo.

Does the undo need to be called also in the recursive function?

This is the negamax class:

```
public class Negamax
{
    private IBoard board;

    public Negamax() {}

    public Move NegamaxRoot(IBoard board, int depth)
    {
        this.board = board.copy();

        int alpha = -999999999, beta = 999999999;
        int val = 0;

        //The move that will be returned
        Move bestMove = null;      
        List<Move> moves = this.board.getMoves();

        for (Move move : moves)
        {
            //IBoard newBoard = board.copy();

            //Make the move
            this.board.make(move, true);
                val = -negamaxRecur(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha);

            //Undo the move
            this.board.undo(move);

            //Keep best move
            if (val > alpha)
            {
                alpha = val;
                bestMove = move;
            }
        }

        //Return the move
        return bestMove;
    }

    private int negamaxRecur(int depth, int alpha, int beta)
    {
        if (depth == 0 || this.board.getWon() != 0)
            return this.board.getScore();

        int val;

        List<Move> moves = this.board.getMoves();
        for (Move move : moves)
        {
            //Make the move
            this.board.make(move, true);
                val = -negamaxRecur(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha);
            this.board.undo(move);

            //Alpha-Beta pruning
            if (val > alpha)
                alpha = val;

            if (alpha >= beta)
                return alpha;
        }

        return alpha;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you haven't understood how passing reference data types to a method works, yet.

Comment: What exactly does "object variables are out of sync" mean? And where is the connection between `board` being a private field and Java passing arguments by value?

Comment: variables are out of sync, for example, after 5 turns, the amount of pieces on the board should be 5 for each player, but they are for example 22, -15